# Which tan method to use?

Tags: methods, trigonometry, angle

When I solve `tan(3.14)` with calculator,it gives `0.0548582`.

When I solve with `Math.tan` the answer is `0.0014`.
When I solve with `Math.atan` the answer is `1.26`.

Which tan `method` to use so that i get answer like my calculator gives and how?

```
    package testclass;

    public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {      
      System.out.println(Math.atan(3.14)); 
      System.out.println(Math.tan(3.143));
      }
    }
```

Comment: math.tan expects radians?

Comment: add a programming language tag, please.

Comment: You realise that tan and atan are two totally different functions?

Comment: yes I do. Didn't know tan-1/ tan inverse/arctan was equivalent to atan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Under no circumstance should tan(3.14) be +0.0014; you've pasted it with the wrong sign.

This is not a programming question.

The three functions you use are **different** functions:

- `atan` is arcustangens, i.e. the inverse to `tan`, so it's completely unrelated.
- your calculator seems to use degrees
- your `Math.tan` function uses radians. 3.14 is "pretty close, but a little smaller" than pi, and sin(3.14) is thus pretty close, but a little bigger than 0, cos(3.14) is thus pretty close, but a little smaller (in absolute terms) than -1, so tan(3.14) is a little less than 0.

**EDIT**: tan x = sin x/cos x, to explain my calculations above.